# Convert a flat set of records (with parent key) to a nested structure?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need a JS loop to change an array of objects into a json object. Here is the sample array of objects:

```
var employees= [
  {name:"Jeff",manager:null,title:"The Pres"},
  {name:"Amy",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Chris",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Dana",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Joe",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Mike",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Aaron",manager:"Jeff",title:"lll"}
];
```

Here is the expected json object:

```
var json = {
    name:"Jeff",
    title:"The Pres",
    children:[{
        name:"Aaron",
        title:"some title",
        children[
            {name:"Amy",title:"some title",children[]},
            {name:"Chris",title:"some title",children:[]},
            {name:"Dana",title:"some title",children:[]},
            {name:"Joe",title:"some title",children:[]},
            {name:"Mike",title:"some title",children:[]
        }]
    }]
};
```

but it is beyond me.

Comment: there is no JSON in this question.

Comment: I have edited the title to the "real question". (JSON is a *text representation* and can be obtained from a JavaScript *object* via `JSON.stringify`. In the above code both snippets show JavaScript *object literals*, from which the JSON format/syntax is *derived*.)

Comment: Why Amy is next to Jeff and it's his child, but Chris is next to Amy and it's her sibling? How can we know if the next element is a child/sibling of the previous one?

Comment: I like how I see it done here by d3noob:

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var employees= [
  {name:"Jeff",manager:null,title:"The Pres"},
  {name:"Amy",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Chris",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Dana",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Joe",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Mike",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
  {name:"Aaron",manager:"Jeff",title:"lll"}
];

​var hash = {};
var root;

for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    var employee = employees[i];
    hash[employee.name] = {
        name:employee.name, manager:employee.manager, title:employee.title, children: []
    };
}
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    var employee = hash[employees[i].name];
    var manager = hash[employee.manager];
    if (manager) {
        manager.children.push(employee);
    } else {
        root = employee;
    }
}
// root is the employee without a manager
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CcdvW/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would write it. Please note that the Big-O bounds for this significantly larger than the answer posted by Onchie (and is roughly `O(n^2)` vs `O(n)`). However, for smaller data-sets this is inconsequential and I find this approach easier to follow.

First I would have a simple function that, for any manager, tells me who the immediate employees are. (Note that this is *just* a standard `filter` function and both [ECMAScript 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) provide higher-order functions to do this with cleaner and more succient code.)

```
function employeesForManager(employees, managerName) {
    var res = []
    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        if (employees[i].manager == managerName) {
            res.push(employees[i])
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Then I would create a recursive function that walks the tree and builds each level. (Likewise, the loop here could be replaced with a simple `map` function.)

```
function giveShape(employees, manager) {
    var immediateEmployees = employeesForManager(employees, manager.name)
    var children = []
    for (var i = 0; i < immediateEmployees.length; i++) {
        children.push(giveShape(employees, immediateEmployees[i]))
    }
    // create a new object to avoid mutating original data
    return {
        name: manager.name,
        title: manager.title,
        children: children       
    }
}
```

And all of this is called:

```
var employees= [
    {name:"Jeff",manager:null,title:"The Pres"},
    {name:"Amy",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
    {name:"Chris",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
    {name:"Dana",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
    {name:"Joe",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
    {name:"Mike",manager:"Aaron",title:"lll"},
    {name:"Aaron",manager:"Jeff",title:"lll"}
]

topManager = employeesForManager(employees, null)[0]
result = giveShape(employees, topManager)  

console.log(result)
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jLwh/)